# Type annotation throws 'cannot find symbol' when using a fully qualified type

Tags: java, types, annotations

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface A {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    private List<@A Integer> integers1;

    private List<@A java.lang.Integer> integers2;
}
```

on
`private List<@A java.lang.Integer> integers2;`
I get an error:

> Error:(20, 21) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class java
>   location: class com.company.Main

is it bug in program?

Comment: They've made some changes recently to Annotations which I haven't completely sussed out, but I vote for "bug in program."  You just can't use annotations on generic type parameters.

Comment: private List<@A Integer> integers1;
works perfect

Comment: This: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8074346?

Comment: very similar case, but now it in generic parameter declaration

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is apparently a normal behavior ([9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4)):

> A type annotation is admissible if both of the following are true:
>
> - The simple name to which the annotation is closest is classified as a *`TypeName`*, not a *`PackageName`*.
> - If the simple name to which the annotation is closest is followed by "." and another *`TypeName`* - that is, the annotation appears as `@Foo T.U` - then `U` denotes an inner class of `T`.

In other words the simple name which `@A` is closest to (`java`) is a *`PackageName`* so the annotation is inadmissible and a compiler error occurs.

And the correct syntax for a type annotation on a qualified name is `java.lang.@A Integer`.